# I just want to know all these sentences are the same meaning and I can use whichever without changing meaning

Tags: sentence-construction

I just want to know all these sentences are the same meaning and I can use whichever without changing meaning.

> 1. I want to have fun when I work.
> 2. I want to work having fun.
> 3. I want to work pleasantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three sentences do not have the exact same meaning.

First of all, your last sentence uses *pleasantly*, a word much weaker than *fun* in that meaning. If you want to work *pleasantly*, the work must not be tedious, boring, but must be *likable*. Saying you want *to work having fun* is much stronger. You really want to enjoy the act of *working* and have the work make you happy.

So the third sentence is definitely different from the first two. Now what about the first vs. the second sentence? I think there's just a slight **difference in focus/stress**. In the first sentence, the focus is on *having fun* and not on the work. The phrase about having fun is the main part, while work modifies that phrase and gives **additional information**. Compare that to the second sentence, where your focus is on *work* and *having fun* is a postmodifier providing **additional information**.

Of course that difference is only very small and I think in most contexts, the first two sentences can be used interchangeably.